# Electromagnetic induction experiment

Tags: electromagnetism

We know that if we have a closed loop with an open surface and when we change magnetic flux through this loop there is an emf therefore a current which results in wire creating a magnetic field in a way to oppose our magnetic flux change. If this loop is not closed can I make the flux change so much that there will be enormous emf so the wire's sides will be polarized and there will be a current flowing for a very very very small amount of time?

Comment: That was how radio waves was first found.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is used to create sparks in various applications, like in an internal combustion engine. There is an ignition coil (a step-up transformer) whose secondary winding is connected to a spark plug, which is essentially two wires that terminate in a small gap, so it doesn't conduct at low voltages.

[image]

[image credit](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-there-is-no-spark-gap-in-this-ignition-coil-circuit-i-e-open-secondary-Where-would-the-voltage-build-up-go)

Current is flown through the primary of the ignition coil, which generates a magnetic flux through the not-quite-closed loop consisting of the secondary winding and the spark plug. The primary current is interrupted by opening a "switch", which causes the magnetic flux to suddenly collapse, causing a large voltage to be induced across the air gap. The air breaks down and a spark is generated, through which the loop is "closed" and current flows.

Comment: This looks very intriguing thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit unclear, but as I understand it I would say this. When you change the magnetic flux in a loop of wire, there is an induced electric field around the loop, as you say. This will cause current to flow in the wire, which is in effect what a generator is. If the loop of wire has a small cut, the electric field around the loop is still there. The line integral of this E field along the wire gives an effective voltage and causes a current to flow. However, since the wire is cut, the current does not traverse the entire wire, but instead causes the charge to "pile up" at the cut.

This basically means that the break in the wire acts as a capacitor, and what you have is an LC circuit (and R if you assume finite conductivity of the wire). Depending on how you vary the magnetic field, you can see this capacitance get fully charged and oppose the voltage induced by the magnetic flux, stopping the current flow.

As the other answer states, depending on circumstances you can get a spark across the gap.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: Also, there would be current for a very short time till the sides become polarized therefore we can detect the opposing magnetic field by this current if we had a very sensitive magnetic field detector?

Comment: The small capacitance at the gap would need a certain amount of charge to oppose the induced voltage form the varying magnetic field. This charge would be the time integral of a current. That current would make a magnetic field. This is no different than when there is no gap. In that case, the current just flows and makes its magnetic field, which as you know from Faraday's law, is in opposition to the changing magnetic flux in the coil.